# REİNDEX SYMFONY ERROR SCREENSHOT

Tags: error, magento2.2, reindex, linux, command

Magento facing indindex issue, please check with below url -

CommandNotFoundException ERROR
**My Screenshot KALİ:** https://image.ibb.co/gu6fWb/Screenshot_from_2017_12_29_03_05_41.png
HELP THANX GUYS

Comment: You have some error while processing commands added to `bin/magento`. This can be trivial and require only manually clearing cache and di folder (var/generation for 2.0.x and 2.1.x or generated for 2.2.x). Of you can have additional module that defines custom command but makes some error during setup.

Comment: `php bin/magento` (just this command), what does it say?